# Load Product By Multiselect Option Value

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

How do I load a product by the value of one of its multiselect options, either option id or frontend value?

**Example:**

```
Product Attribute "Size", Values "Large", "Medium", "Small"

// Desired behaviour
$productSearch->loadByAttributeOption('size', 'large');
```

Comment: `$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);`

Comment: I do not know the product - I only know the attribute value.